# Pick file system for old hard drive

Tags: linux, filesystems, zfs, smartctl

The hard drive of my laptop is a 10 years old fujitsu mhw2160bh pl.

The smartctl says the hard drive is as "healthy" as a new hard drive of the same model in 2008 with the same "pre-fail" values (values for new hard drive: https://sourceforge.net/p/smartmontools/mailman/message/20485474/)

I want to use the laptop to serve mediawiki with centos.

What file system / software can I use to reduce the potential data corruption?

Would ZFS help in this case?

Comment: i guess zfs won't help unless i setup a raid.

Comment: ZFS can provide a limited amount of data redundancy by setting the "copies" property. This would help you in the event of a complete drive failure, but it could mitigate data corruption in one area of the drive. For example, "zfs set copies=2" will keep an extra copy of all data on your single drive.

Comment: ^ that should read "wouldn't help you in the event of a complete drive failure"